# How do I get AngularJs UI-Router to load components for AngularJs 1.6.1 app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have followed the documentation on the UI-Router site to the point that my code for configuring the $StateProvider is practically identical, but I cannot get my Components to load.  I am able to see the html pages referenced in my templateUrl but the controllers are not being accessed.  Also, when I provide a Controller reference in the state route it errors suggesting that the controller is not register

The first component on the index page:

```
<supply-chain-admin ng-cloak></supply-chain-admin>

(function () {
"use strict"

var module = angular.module("SCAdmin");

function AppController($timeout) {

    var vm = this; // vm = ViewModel
    vm.isNewBlankLoad = false;
    vm.selectedMenuItem;
    vm.changeMenu = true;

    vm.$onInit = function () {
        vm.changeMenu = true;
    }

    vm.collapseMainMenu = function (isCollapsed) {
        vm.changeMenu = isCollapsed;
        $timeout(function () { equalheight('.menuListItem'); }, 10);
    };
}

module.component("supplyChainAdmin", {
    templateUrl: "/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/SCAdminApp/SupplyChainAdmin.html",
    bindings: {
    },
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: ['$timeout', AppController]
});
```

})();

The inside this components html file:

```
<main-menu show-menu="vm.changeMenu"></main-menu>
<main-content show-menu="vm.changeMenu"></main-content>
```

Inside the main-menu component:

```
<div id="menuleft" ng-class="{hideMenu:!vm.showMenu,slide:vm.showMenu}">
<div id="mainMenuHeader">
    <a class="pull-right" id="mainMenuToggleLink" ng-click="vm.toggleMenu()">
        <img src="/Content/images/menu.png" />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="mainMenu">
    <ul class="menuList" ng-class="{hideMenu:vm.showMenu,slide:!vm.showMenu}"><!-- the :: symbol represents one time binding -->
        <li title="{{ ::menuItem.ToolTip }}" class="menuListItem" ng-repeat="menuItem in vm.menuItems" ng-class="{ active: menuItem.Link == vm.selectedMenuItem }" resize-normal>
            <button class="menuNotifications pull-right" ng-show="menuItem.Notification.length" popover="{{ ::menuItem.NotificationMessage }}" popover-trigger="focus" popover-placement="right" popover-append-to-body="true">{{ ::menuItem.Notification }}</button>
            <a ng-click="vm.menuItemChanged(menuItem.Link)" ui-sref="{{ ::menuItem.Link }}">
                <h1 ng-show="vm.showMenu"><span class="{{ ::menuItem.MenuIconClass }}"></span> {{ ::menuItem.Title }} <i class="line"></i></h1>
                <p ng-hide="vm.showMenu"><span class="{{ ::menuItem.MenuIconClass }}"></span> <i class="line"></i></p>

                <div class="menuItemContent" ng-class="{hide:!vm.showMenu}">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li ng-repeat="pointItem in menuItem.MenuItemPoints">
                            <div class="fa large-glyphicon {{ ::pointItem.IconClass }}" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                            <div class="menuSubItemText">&nbsp;{{ ::pointItem.DisplayText }}&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="menuSubItemValue">&nbsp;{{ ::pointItem.DisplayValue }}&nbsp;</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
(function () {
"use strict"

var module = angular.module("SCAdmin");

module.component("mainMenu", {
    templateUrl: "/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/MainMenu/MainMenu.html",
    bindings: {
        showMenu: "="
    },
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: ["$http", '$timeout', '$state', mainMenuController]
});

function mainMenuController($http, $timeout, $state) {

    var vm = this; // vm = ViewModel

    vm.isNewBlankLoad = false;
    vm.menuItems = [];

    vm.selectedMenuItem;

    vm.$onInit = function () {
        fetchMenuItems($http, $state).then(function (data) {
            if (data.length) {

                for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
                    if (data[i].MenuItemType === 1) {

                        vm.menuItems.push({ Link: 'Items', ToolTip: 'Items', Title: 'My Items', MenuItemType: 1, Notification: data[i].Notification, NotificationMessage: data[i].NotificationMessage, MenuItemPoints: data[i].MenuItemPoints, MenuIconClass: 'fa fa-tags' });
                    }
                    if (data[i].MenuItemType === 2) {
                        vm.menuItems.push({ Link: 'Vendors', ToolTip: 'Vendor', Title: 'My Vendors', MenuItemType: 2, Notification: data[i].Notification, NotificationMessage: data[i].NotificationMessage, MenuItemPoints: data[i].MenuItemPoints, MenuIconClass: 'fa fa-id-card' });
                    }
                    if (data[i].MenuItemType === 3) {
                        vm.menuItems.push({ Link: 'Facilities', ToolTip: 'Facilities', Title: 'My Facilities', MenuItemType: 2, Notification: data[i].Notification, NotificationMessage: data[i].NotificationMessage, MenuItemPoints: data[i].MenuItemPoints, MenuIconClass: 'fa fa-university' });
                    }
                    if (data[i].MenuItemType === 4) {
                        vm.menuItems.push({ Link: 'Departments', ToolTip: 'Departments', Title: 'My Departments', MenuItemType: 2, Notification: data[i].Notification, NotificationMessage: data[i].NotificationMessage, MenuItemPoints: data[i].MenuItemPoints, MenuIconClass: 'fa fa-bed' });
                    }
                    if (data[i].MenuItemType === 5) {
                        vm.menuItems.push({ Link: 'Pars', ToolTip: 'Pars', Title: 'My PARs', MenuItemType: 2, Notification: data[i].Notification, NotificationMessage: data[i].NotificationMessage, MenuItemPoints: data[i].MenuItemPoints, MenuIconClass: 'fa fa-stethoscope' });
                    }
                    if (data[i].MenuItemType === 6) {
                        vm.menuItems.push({ Link: 'Maintenance', ToolTip: 'Maintenance', Title: 'Maintenance', MenuItemType: 2, Notification: data[i].Notification, NotificationMessage: data[i].NotificationMessage, MenuItemPoints: data[i].MenuItemPoints, MenuIconClass: 'fa fa-wrench' });
                    }
                }

                vm.selectedMenuItem = $state.current.name != null ? $state.current.name : vm.menuItems[0].ToolTip;
            }
        });
    };

    vm.menuItemChanged = function (selectMenuItem) {
        vm.selectedMenuItem = selectMenuItem;
    }

    vm.menuItems = vm.menuItems;

    vm.toggleMenu = function () {
        vm.showMenu = (vm.showMenu) ? false : true;
        $timeout(function () { equalheight('.menuListItem'); }, 10);
    }
}

function fetchMenuItems($http) {
    return $http.get(SupplyChainAdminUrl + 'Menu/GetMenuItems/', { params: { domain: CurrentUserDomain, userName: CurrentUserUserName } }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

})();

Inside the main-content component:

```
<div id="contentFromMenu" ng-class="{hideMenu:vm.showMenu,slide:!vm.showMenu}">
<div class="overlay" ng-class="{show:vm.showMenu}" ng-click="vm.collapseMenu()"></div>
<div id="menuContentContainer">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

```
(function () {

"use strict"

var module = angular.module("SCAdmin");

module.component("mainContent", {
    templateUrl: "/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/MainContent/MainContent.html",
    require: {
        'parent': '^supplyChainAdmin'
    },
    bindings: {
        showMenu: "<"
    },
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: ["$http", '$timeout', mainContentController]

});

function mainContentController($timeout) {

    var vm = this; // vm = Viewvm

    vm.$onInit = function () {

    }

    vm.collapseMenu = function () {
        //the parameter sets the show menu property to false;
        vm.parent.collapseMainMenu(false);
    };
};
```

})();

The router which is inside the app.js module file:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("SCAdmin", ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'jQueryScrollbar', 'ngSanitize', 'angular.vertilize']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Items');
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location, $window, $timeout) {

        //We can write authorization / part access checks here.

        //what this function returns will be set as the $location.url
        var path = $location.path(), normalized = path.toLowerCase();

        if (path != normalized) {

            //alert(path);

            //instead of returning a new url string, I'll just change the $location.path directly so I don't have to worry about constructing a new url string and so a new state change is not triggered
            //$location.replace().path(normalized);
        }

        // because we've returned nothing, no state change occurs
    });

    $stateProvider
        .state('Items', {
            url: '/Items',
            component: 'items',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Items/Items.html',
            //onEnter: function(){
            //    alert('entering the Items state');
            //}
        })
        .state('Vendors', {
            url: '/Vendors',
            component: 'Vendors',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Vendors/Vendors.html',
        })
        .state('Vendors.VendorList', {
            url: '/List',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Vendors/List/VendorList.html'
        })
        .state('Facilities', {
            url: '/Facilities',
            component: 'facilities',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Facilities/Facilities.html',
        })
        .state('Departments', {
            url: '/Departments',
            component: 'departments',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Departments/Departments.html',
        })
        .state('Pars', {
            url: '/Pars',
            component: 'pars',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Pars/Pars.html',
        })
        .state('Maintenance', {
            url: '/Maintenance',
            component: 'maintenance',
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Maintenance/Maintenance.html',
        });
})

app.run(function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', function (event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        $rootScope.stateIsLoading = true;
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        $timeout(function () { $rootScope.stateIsLoading = false; }, 300);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $timeout(function () { $rootScope.stateIsLoading = false; }, 300);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function (event, viewConfig) {
        //$rootScope.stateIsLoading = true;
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, viewConfig) {
        //$rootScope.stateIsLoading = false;
    });
})
```

}());

I am aware that the nested routes are not correctly configured.  My focus is on the "Items" state for this post.  The html loads, but the component does not.

Comment: So according to the UI-Router documentation the state property "Component" is how it identifies what component to load.  I have found that in previous version what you say as to be true, but they had updated the code base to make it possible.  I really think that I may be doing something incorrect.  You can find the information I speak of here: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component

Comment: can you show a sample of your route?  yes, in the *new* ui-router, you can route to a `component` (not `Component`, btw).  Also, components manage their own controller, so you can't reference a controller intended for a component directly.

Comment: @Claies You are correct, you provide a controller directly in the "component" which I am doing.  That is why I know that the component is not being loaded, besides it does not show attached to the "ui-view" element when I inspect the page.  I know this should happen because I see other components, that are not being loaded be the router attached to a "ui-view" when I inspect it.  Another reason is that my "$onInit()" function, or any other code on the controller, is not processing.

Comment: I have a root component that nests two other components.  The two child components contain a left nav menu and the main content which lays right.  The main content component is where the first "ui-view" is placed and when a menu item is selected the ui-router loads the appropriate html file listed in the state.  It however does not access / load the component itself.  The component that are supposed to be loaded are meant to be the content pages of the site.

Comment: A component is basically a controller and a template. So you shouldn't specify the templateUrl in the state definition: the component defines it already.

Comment: what does the definition for the component in question look like?  you went from showing no code to showing so much code it's not obvious what you are trying to work with.  You say that the `Items` state is the route you are trying to solve, which implies the `items` component is the problem, but I don't see a definition for an `items` component in the code you posted....

Comment: Just to confirm this: are you using uiRouter 1.0?

Comment: @Claies The component template that I am trying to load only has a simple message in it: "Items Content".   Yes, I am using 1.0.0-cr.1

Comment: @Claies here is the code for the Items conponent: 

    (function () {  }

Comment: @Claies here is the code for the Items conponent: 

    (function () { 
        'use strict';

        var module = angular.module("SCAdmin");

        module.component("items", { 
            templateUrl: "/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Items/Itemsl.html",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            controller: [ItemsController]
        });

        function ItemsController(){
            var vm = this;
            alert('boo');
            vm.$onInit = function(){
                 alert('boo init');
            }
         }
    }

Comment: @Claies, I have discovered part of the issue but Im not sure how to correct it.  I am working on it.  To get it to work in plunker I had to remove <base "/" /> from the _layout file and the $locationProvider.htm5Mode(true) call in my module.js file. I am using Microsoft MVC by the way.  Once I did that it worked.  There are a couple other differences between what I have in plunker and what I have in my MVC app.  Plunker all my files are in the root. MVC my paths are scripts folder, SCAdminApp folder, and then an individual folder for each component (script and html). The paths appear to be it.

Comment: everything you are describing here is suggesting that the problem is with your MVC setup, and not angular at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like problem is in your state definitions with components, for example:

```
.state('Vendors', {
        url: '/Vendors',
        component: 'Vendors',
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/SupplyChainAdmin/Vendors/Vendors.html',
    })
```

As of latest ui-router you need to specify routes with components providing route name, url, component and resolver(optionally)

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'Vendors',
  url: '/Vendors',
  component: 'Vendors'
});
```

You don't need to provide templateUrl in state definition as you've already set this inside your component's definition.
Also if you change URL but don't want to reload page you can supply additional state definition param `reloadOnSearch : false`
Like:

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'Vendors',
  url: '/Vendors',
  component: 'Vendors',
  reloadOnSearch : false
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry it has been so long, but actually the first mentioning of 'Vendors' is the name.